# Better way to transfer CSS animation into flutter project

Tags: css, flutter, flutter-animation, codepen

I recently co-worked with other designers. They used to provide some CSS animation examples from codepen that need to be applied to the current project. The animation may be simple or complicated. For example:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}

.music {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.music .bar {
  width: 12px;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  animation: up_down 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes up_down {
  0%,
  100% {
    height: 2px;
  }
  50% {
    height: 80px;
  }
}

.music .bar:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: purple;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.music .bar:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: crimson;
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
}

.music .bar:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: deeppink;
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

.music .bar:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: orange;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

.music .bar:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: gold;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.music .bar:nth-child(6) {
  background-color: gold;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.music .bar:nth-child(7) {
  background-color: orange;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

.music .bar:nth-child(8) {
  background-color: deeppink;
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

.music .bar:nth-child(9) {
  background-color: crimson;
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
}

.music .bar:nth-child(10) {
  background-color: purple;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class='music'>
  <div class='bar'></div>
  <div class='bar'></div>
  <div class='bar'></div>
  <div class='bar'></div>
  <div class='bar'></div>
  <div class='bar'></div>
  <div class='bar'></div>
  <div class='bar'></div>
  <div class='bar'></div>
  <div class='bar'></div>
</div>
```

I crafted the animation from Flutter Canvas once, but also wonder if there is a better way to apply the CSS animation to the Flutter Project (which used to be very easy when applying it to the website)

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**:
write this code in file .html inside assets folder

```
<div class='music'>
  <div class='bar'></div>
  <div class='bar'></div>
  <div class='bar'></div>
  <div class='bar'></div>
  <div class='bar'></div>
  <div class='bar'></div>
  <div class='bar'></div>
  <div class='bar'></div>
  <div class='bar'></div>
  <div class='bar'></div>
</div>


<style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: black;
  }

  .music {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
  }

  .music .bar {
    width: 12px;
    height: 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    animation: up_down 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
  }

  @keyframes up_down {

    0%,
    100% {
      height: 2px;
    }

    50% {
      height: 80px;
    }
  }

  .music .bar:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: purple;
    animation-delay: 1s;
  }

  .music .bar:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: crimson;
    animation-delay: 0.8s;
  }

  .music .bar:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: deeppink;
    animation-delay: 0.6s;
  }

  .music .bar:nth-child(4) {
    background-color: orange;
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
  }

  .music .bar:nth-child(5) {
    background-color: gold;
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
  }

  .music .bar:nth-child(6) {
    background-color: gold;
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
  }

  .music .bar:nth-child(7) {
    background-color: orange;
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
  }

  .music .bar:nth-child(8) {
    background-color: deeppink;
    animation-delay: 0.6s;
  }

  .music .bar:nth-child(9) {
    background-color: crimson;
    animation-delay: 0.8s;
  }

  .music .bar:nth-child(10) {
    background-color: purple;
    animation-delay: 1s;
  }
</style>
```

**secondly**: Install webview_flutter package, Then write the following:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class HtmlWidgetExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const HtmlWidgetExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<HtmlWidgetExample> createState() => _HtmlWidgetExampleState();
}

class _HtmlWidgetExampleState extends State<HtmlWidgetExample> {
  String? htmlContent;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadHtml();
  }

  loadHtml() async {
    htmlContent = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/yourFile.html');
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (htmlContent == null) return const SizedBox();
    return WebView(
      initialUrl: Uri.dataFromString(
        htmlContent!,
        mimeType: 'text/html',
        encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'),
      ).toString(),
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      onPageFinished: (String url) {},
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did your solution only support the Android and iOS platforms? By the way, does your code not use the latest version of webview_flutter package?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to tell you that I used version ^2.8.0 for "webview_flutter" package, and it works in my application on all platforms.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but there are too many issues when I try to use webview inside Flutter (like Scroll, click, and performance issues) I think drawing it on my own may be a more reliable way if there is no better solution.